# how to share database between virtualbox guests

Tags: database, phpmyadmin, virtualbox, windows-server-2008, wampserver

I have installed windows server 2016 as a guest in VirtualBox and windows 7 and centos7 as geusts aswell.
I have configured a private network between them and dhcp and dns from windows server and it seems its working fine. Dhcp distributed ip's to the other guests.
To make it short w7 and centos are connected to windows server via dhcp.
I have installed wamp server on windows server and I want windows 7 and centos7 to access the database aswell.
I tried typing the ip/phpmyadmin but doesnt seem to work.
anyone had a similar project and can help me would be apreciated.
(sorry for my english I hope you understand)

Comment: Welcome as a new user to [SO]. Please take the [tour] and also read [ASK]. As is your question is too broad and unspecified and likely to be closed soon.

Comment: im trying to find someone who could understand what i mean because it's kinda hard to explain the situation